# How to calculate grades based on percentage using ireports

Tags: jasper-reports

In ireports how to calculate the grade based on percentage.

- Variable1 is sum of total values
- variable2 is percentage.

based on variable2 grades have to display

```
if(variable2>=95) ? "A+" : if(variable2>=75) ? "B"
```

and so on. I have tried with "printwhenexpresssion" property but its giving error

How can i represent this in ireports?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doing comparison if else in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437323/doing-comparison-if-else-in-jasperreports)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a text field and it's expression will be :

```
variable>= 95 ? "A+" : (variable>= 75 ? "B" : "something")
```

> according to [Java Ternary Operator inside ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146723/java-ternary-operator-inside-ternary-operator-how-evaluated)

It will be evaluated as you want